# How to handle scaling down ECS containers when a Celery worker completes a task?

Tags: django, celery, amazon-sqs

How can I handle scale-down policies properly when using SQS as a broker and celery with celery beat for task scheduling in a Django app?

I have successfully created a scale-up policy that adds new containers when there is a new message in SQS. However, I am facing challenges in implementing a scale-down autoscaling policy. When I choose the "NumberOfMessagesSent" metric for scale-down, it removes tasks before the worker finishes their job. This becomes problematic especially with long-running tasks that can last for several hours.

My goal is to ensure that if a celery task's status is "STARTED," the worker responsible for executing the task should be kept alive until the status changes to "SUCCESS" or "FAILURE." How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ECS uses docker to build, start and stop containers. When the scale down process begins, ECS first sends SIGTERM followed by a SIGKILL if the container doesn't shutdown by itself. It is the responsibility of init process(PID 1) to shut down gracefully. But incase if the process doesn't have a SIGTERM handler or doesn't shutdown within a predefined duration(by default this is 30 seconds), ECS forcefully kills down the container. You can read more about ECS [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/graceful-shutdowns-with-ecs/).For a general understanding of docker and zombie reaping problem, you can start reading from [here](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8916785).

Coming to your case with Celery, you should do the following:

1. Run celery worker as the init process(PID 1).

   It's very common in initial stages to run celery inside a bash script. But this comes with its own problems.

   a. bash assumes PID 1 with celery as its child process and it behaves very differently as init. It just ignores SIGTERM sent by the docker and celery doesn't even know that a SIGTERM has been issued and continues picking up new tasks. To overcome this you have to add a trap to catch the signal and pass that to celery, which is error prone.

   b. **exec** form can be used, after which celery assumes the role of PID 1 and handles SIGTERM by not accepting any new tasks and waiting till the current task is complete. This should work fine unless you face any issues with zombie processes
2. Use a library like [tini](https://github.com/krallin/tini) or dumb-init which passes the signals to child process as expected while still handling zombie processes.

But as you mentioned your task taking time in hours, celery inside ECS doesn't suit your use case unless you split into smaller tasks which take less than 120 seconds to complete. You can read more about the **stopTimeout** and other container configurations [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_ContainerDefinition.html).

Answer (score 2):

After many hours of testing and research I have found a solution that works pretty well with scale-down alert based on messages visible on SQS.

This solution is referred to as "task scale-in protection," and detailed instructions on how to utilize it can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-scale-in-protection.html). Basically when alert state changes to In alarm it is changing desired task to 0 but it is not removing any containers until worker finishes the task which is sufficient solution in my case.

I am sharing a sample Python function below that enables toggling of the protection status from "true" to "false" and vice versa. I hope that it will help someone.

```
def toggle_scale_in_protection(self, *, enable: bool = True, expire_in_minutes: int = 2880):
    response = self._request(
        path="/task-protection/v1/state",
        data={"ProtectionEnabled": enable, "ExpiresInMinutes": expire_in_minutes},
    )

    try:
        return response["protection"]["ProtectionEnabled"]
    except KeyError:
        raise self.Error(f"Task scale-in protection endpoint error: {response=}")
```